# Confusion about padding and masking TF inputs when there are zeros in the data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a character-level many-to-many RNN and the input vocabulary size is 87 and the output class size is 9 classes.  Originally each character in the input was given an id from `{0,...,86}` and each output class was given an id from `{0,...8}`.  Also my loss function was `tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

The problem is that the inputs were of varying lengths so I needed to use zero padding.  The model trained without error however the problem was that the model had no way of distinguishing a zero that was a pad value from a zero that was a character or output class value.

I think that I solved it by incrementing the character and output class ids such that they are now `{1,...,87}` and `{1,...,9}` respectively.  I also needed to increment the input and output sizes of the model I was training.  The results look ok and it doesn't look like the trained model ever predicts a zero (i.e. a pad value) so that is good.  But my question is is this the correct way to deal with zero id's in your dataset when you are using zero padding?

Comment: You can use an Embedding layer before the RNN. In Keras, the Embedding layer has a `mask_zero` argument which discards the 0 values. So you can use the padding functionality easily. However, in this setting you cannot still use 0 as a class value in your vocabulary.

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal that's what I ended up doing